# Windows 10 Linux Subsystem. How to install MongoDB

Tags: linux, windows, bash, mongodb, ubuntu

Recently published a new update to the Windows 10 Anniversary Update includes Linux Subsystem [based on Ubuntu 14.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjOrl.jpg) and now I want to all of my working environment was in this Linux Subsystem.

I try to install MongoDB with this instructions from official website https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

After installation is complete I try to run mongodb with

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

but have follow error

```
User@DESKTOP-TPQIRNP:/mnt/c/Users/User$ sudo service mongod start
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
mongod: unrecognized service
```

How to install the latest stable version of MongoDB without errors ?

Comment: Solution provided at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62496101/4567160) location helped me solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, we can see some solutions to this problem in this `Microsoft/BashOnWindows` issue here https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/796

One of the working solutions https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/796#issuecomment-238048520

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the

> mongod: unrecognized service

issue by performing following tasks:

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/mongod
```

then copy and paste the content from [this url](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mongodb/mongo/master/debian/init.d) and save it (you can use vim or any other text editor)

After that give executable permission

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/mongod
```

Now you will be able to start the service by following command

```
sudo service mongod start
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore the error and keep going. From [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/791), the explanation:

> this error can be safely ignored. WSL doesn't use Upstart to start
>   processes at system boot. If you work closely with Upstart, this might
>   cause some surprises for you; the message is informative to people who
>   work directly with initctl, upstart, etc that WSL doesn't yet expose
>   that functionality. If that's not your use case, then as you have
>   observed, mongodb itself works.

Keep in mind that WSL is still beta and errors will be everywhere!