# Installing MongoDB in WSL

Tags: mongodb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was trying to install MongoDB in WSL running Ubuntu 18.04 after seeing [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/python/databases) documentation. But MongoDB says that:

> IMPORTANT
> The `mongodb` package provided by Ubuntu is not maintained by MongoDB Inc. and conflicts with the official `mongodb-org` package. If you have already installed the mongodb package on your Ubuntu system, you must first uninstall the mongodb package before proceeding with these instructions.

MongoDB also says that WSL doesn't support `mongodb-org`

> WINDOWS SUBSYSTEM FOR LINUX (WSL) - UNSUPPORTED
> MongoDB does not support the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).

So, I installed `mongod` using `sudo apt install mongodb` and when I ran `mongo` it shows the error:

```
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-06-21T13:33:40.606+0530 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017
```

Is there is a way to install the appropriate package and make it running?

Comment: I think these are the instructions you should follow to install mongodb on WSL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-database#install-mongodb. They work for me.

Comment: @msoutopico They work for me too, but the problem is that it's an outdated version

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I have come across this situation recently.

Even though MongoDB says that it is not supported in WSL, you can actually install it. So, I suggest you follow that steps given in MongoDB docs.

**Note** : If you have already installed `mongodb` please remove all those before you install `mongodb-org` since it may cause some issues during installation :

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mongo-tools
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mongodb-server-core
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
```

For installing mongodb community edition, I have added the commands below:

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get install gnupg
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Now, to get mongoDB running,

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/mongod
```

and paste the contents in this [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mongodb/mongo/master/debian/init.d) into the file and save it.

```
#give permissions
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/mongod

#start the service
sudo service mongod start
```

Now, you can run `mongo` to reach the database.

Comment: Running the command `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org` gives me multiple errors:        

`System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
dpkg: error processing package mongodb-org-server (--configure):
 installed mongodb-org-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1`

The failure to setup mongodb-org-server leads to dependency problems for mongodb-org which depends on it.

Comment: Also, starting the database using `sudo service mongod start` fails.

Comment: Yes, same for me, same as @ConnerDassen. See my comment to the original post above.

Comment: @ConnerDassen Yes but the solution above worked for me. I am under WSL2. I can confirm that `sudo service mongod start` started successfully.

Comment: `sudo service mongod start` now runs but gives this error -  `/etc/init.d/mongod: 1: nit.d: not found`, it shows starting database mongod but doesn't start it actually. (WSL2)

Comment: here's a nice documentation by microsoft on installing databases on WSL2 -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-database

Comment: @kybrdbnd this tutorial installs an old version (3.6) of MongoDB

Comment: @ConnerDassen You can try removing it by `sudo apt-get purge mongodb-*` then do it again

Answer (score 7):

[@bonyem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6921594/bonyem)'s solution works if you try on Ubuntu 18.04 (and apparently in 19.10) but not in 20.04. WSL version should be 2 (please see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) to update WSL).

You also need to "fake" the bash binary by following the steps mentioned in https://github.com/shayne/wsl2-hacks to make systemctl work.

Comment: I got this to work in 20.04, but I also needed to change the ownership of `/var/lib/mongodb` to `mongodb`.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me.

Run `sudo apt install mongodb`

Then after that installs run `sudo service mongodb start`

It will say `* Starting database mongodb`

And after that I can connect using `mongo`

Comment: This installs version 3.6 and not the latest version 4.4

Comment: ERROR: Package 'mongodb' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 6):

I tried all the methods above but none of the methods worked. I came across Microsoft's official documentation and everything works like a charm.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-database#install-mongodb

Comment: After do this, if on the log (/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log) appears this message: 
    Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Operation not permitted"
Delete mongodb-27017.sock (sudo rm -r /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock)
Then start

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way to bypass this issue is to run MongoDB on Windows. You'll still be able to connect from WSL2 over localhost.

For me, [@bonyem's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62496101/5943840) resulted in an error:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

I'm going to install Mongo 4.4. Many instructions were taken from @Lyubosumaz's directions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64809181/5943840).

Get rid of all your Mongo PPAs.

```
~ ❯ sudo ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
mongodb-org-4.4.list  yarn.list
~ ❯ sudo rm -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list
```

Remove all Mongo packages and bits and pieces.

```
sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mongo-tools
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mongodb-org
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mongodb-org-server
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mongodb-server-core
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mongodb-org-mongos
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mongodb-org-shell
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mongodb-org-tools
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
yes | sudo apt autoremove
```

Add new PPA and install Mongo 4.4.

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

You'll get the same error from before. This is caused by mongodb-org package trying to use `systemctl` to start the DB after install ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/i2r7oa/cant_install_mongodb_on_wsl_1_ubuntu_2004/g06ntkr?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)). Notice that the same error is thrown when running the command manually.

```
~ ❯ sudo systemctl start mongod
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

However, running `mongod` should still work!

If you run into errors when running `mongod`, you might need to modify some permissions and create a data directory. I found the answer to these issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34290982/5943840), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43033484/5943840), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42447303/5943840).

```
sudo chown $USER /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
sudo mkdir -p /data/db
sudo chown -R $USER /data/db
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried some of the answers above, it did not work for me.
Then I followed a guide [1](https://dev.to/seanwelshbrown/installing-mongodb-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-2-19m9):

1. Update ubuntu packages
2. Install MongoDB on the command line
3. Set up your local database
4. Creating the folders and permissions

It worked in my case!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make [bonyem's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62495999/installing-mongodb-in-wsl/62496101#62496101) work on Ubuntu 22 just now with the following addition for local dev.

```
sudo service mongod stop
sudo rm -rf /tmp/mongod*
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chmod -R a+wxr /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into an error when using @bonyem's solution. I saw this error in the logs that it did not have permission to write to `/var/run/mongod.pid`. I saw this by running `sudo cat /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` I had to make a few permission changes and changes to the init.d script to get it to work. first I changed this line `PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid` to `PIDFILE=/var/run/mongodb/$NAME.pid`.

Then ran the command `sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/run/mongodb/` I tried it at first without the -R and each time the .pid file was created it was owned by root. Adding the -R seemed to permanently make new files owned by mongodb. @user296656's answer helped me figure that out!

After doing that running `sudo service mongodb start` worked and the error was gone in the logs.