# can't start mongodb server in ubuntu windows

Tags: mongodb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

i just install mongodb on ubuntu windows using `sudo apt-get -y install mongodb`. after installation was finsished, i want to start using `sudo systemctl start mongodb` and it show like this in terminal

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

then i found the alternative way to start the server in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197246/system-has-not-been-booted-with-systemd-as-init-system-pid-1-cant-operate). i Tried using `sudo /etc/init.d/mongodb start` and it gave me error like this
`* Starting database mongodb              [fail]` i think it's failed to start the server.

anyone can help me to solve this issue ? thanks in advance !

Comment: `service mongodb start` https://askubuntu.com/a/1241306/870211

Comment: I used this solution and it seem working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62495999/installing-mongodb-in-wsl

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Thanks David Makogo for guiding to formulate a proper answer , I too had same problem and sorted out following couple of steps, therefore thought to share the steps and information related to this issue

Based on the support of underlying OS's built-in init System (a service management system in Linux)

we can perform/execute systemctl or service commands

Mainly, There are two types : namely **systemd (systemctl)** or **System V Init (service)**

WSL installed Ubuntu falls into **init** category , Anyway, you can check which type it by

```
**ps --no-headers -o comm 1**
```

Currently ,WSL does not  support for systemd and no default scripts installed during installation of mongoDB

Anyway, we can execute service commands but we have to install init scripts beforehand, you can download & set permissions

```
**curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mongodb/mongo/master/debian/init.d | 
  sudo tee /etc/init.d/mongodb >/dev/null

 sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/mongodb**
```

Also create & set directories where you want to store data

```
 **mkdir -p ~/data/db
 mongod --dbpath ~/data/db         #set to path while running mongo**
```

Next you can attempt the service commands based on success of all above points

```
**sudo service mongodb start/stop/status**
```

Also you can refer official microsoft guides for install mongoDB and differences

Answer (score -1):

Refer this

it contains how to install MongoDB (version 5.0) on WSL (Ubuntu 20.04): avoiding wsl systemd issues as it currently does not support

Comment: seems url not there https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-database#install-mongodb

Comment: FYI link-only answers are not valid answers. At best, this should be a comment, but... not an answer. Also: Any additional content should be edited into your answer, not included as follow-on comments.