# Problems Installing Mongodb on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mongodb, installation, ubuntu-20.04

Will give a quick context. I was strict to the manual:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

1. wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc | sudo apt-key add -
2. echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list
3. sudo apt-get update
4. sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
5. sudo systemctl start mongod
6. sudo systemctl status mongod

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-11-12 03:11:07 EET; 1min 8s ago
Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
Process: 6780 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=14)
Main PID: 6780 (code=exited, status=14)
systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=14/n/a
systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

7. mongo

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

Then tried to fix this status=14/n/a with:

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

and other stuff

Then deleted mongodb with:

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
sudo apt remove mongodb
sudo apt purge mongodb
sudo apt autoremove
```

And install it the same way from above with the same result. I need help.

That's the etc/mongod.conf

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Here is the mongod logs from var/log/mongodb/mongod.log the file is 550 liner and I copied only the last log:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-12T15:30:35.643+02:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"main","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-12T15:30:35.645+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-12T15:30:35.655+02:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-12T15:30:35.655+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-12T15:30:35.656+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":9759,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongodb","architecture":"64-bit","host":"lubo"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-12T15:30:35.656+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.1","gitVersion":"ad91a93a5a31e175f5cbf8c69561e788bbc55ce1","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-12T15:30:35.656+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"20.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-12T15:30:35.656+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1","port":27017},"processManagement":{"timeZoneInfo":"/usr/share/zoneinfo"},"storage":{"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongodb","journal":{"enabled":true}},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-12T15:30:35.657+02:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":50922,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"An incomplete repair has been detected! This is likely because a repair operation unexpectedly failed before completing. MongoDB will not start up again without --repair."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-12T15:30:35.657+02:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":50922,"file":"src/mongo/db/storage/storage_engine_init.cpp","line":86}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-12T15:30:35.657+02:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

Update ATM I tried another reinstall this time with guide from stackoverflow:

1. sudo apt-get install --reinstall mongodb
   (had error - Errors were encountered while processing)
2. sudo systemctl daemon-reload
3. sudo apt update/upgrate
4. sudo apt install mongodb
   (The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required)
5. sudo apt autoremove
6. sudo systemctl status mongodb
   (Main process exited, code=exited, status=100/n/a)
7. sudo mongo

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.8
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("667c92c8-0a10-4adb-bcf6-ba045f280034") }
MongoDB server version: 3.6.8
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
For interactive help, type "help".
For more comprehensive documentation, see
    http://docs.mongodb.org/
Questions? Try the support group
    http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user
Server has startup warnings: 
2020-11-12T17:33:37.780+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
2020-11-12T17:33:37.780+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2020-11-12T17:33:37.780+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2020-11-12T17:33:38.722+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2020-11-12T17:33:38.722+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2020-11-12T17:33:38.722+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2020-11-12T17:33:38.722+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

8. sudo apt-get install libc6
   (libc6 is already the newest version (2.31-0ubuntu9.1))
9. sudo systemctl status mongod

```
 mongod.service
     Loaded: not-found (Reason: Unit mongod.service not found.)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-11-12 17:33:37 EET; 7min ago
   Main PID: 16038 (mongod)
     CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
             └─16038 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf

ное 12 17:33:37 lubo systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
ное 12 17:34:03 lubo systemd[1]: mongod.service: Current command vanished from the unit file, execution of the command list won't be resumed.
```

Now I belive we have working mongod, only to connect it with mongod.service

Comment: How does your `/etc/mongod.conf` look like?

Comment: Ok, I put is in the question, should have done it from beginning. This line bindIp: 127.0.0.1, tried commenting it and bindIp: true at some point

Comment: What do you have in your logfile (`/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`)?

Comment: Ok, I added a log. `mongod.log` and `mongodb.log` are pretty lengthy so I copied only the last log from `mongod.log`

Comment: "src/mongo/db/storage/storage_engine init.cpp","line":86

Comment: Have a look at this line: `"An incomplete repair has been detected! This is likely because a repair operation unexpectedly failed before completing. MongoDB will not start up again without --repair.`

Comment: Ok, that's good to know. I tried command repair at some point and it failed. Sorry for being such a junior. Will add more info to the question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

start with removing all PPA repositories for mongodb, then:

```bash
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
sudo apt remove mongodb
sudo apt purge mongodb
sudo apt autoremove
sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
sudo apt-get install gnupg
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
sudo apt-get install libc6
sudo service mongod start
sudo service mongod status
```

This helped me with the issue

Comment: Amazing. I have no idea why but this fixed this for me. Thanks!

Comment: what's the ppa of mongodb? how do I remove all the PPA?

Comment: Thanks, You helped a lot. "sudo apt-get upgrade" and "sudo apt upgrade" commands are redundant. I suggest to remove them from the answer.

Comment: I don't know why but this answer also worked for me, even though I've done it many time.
I think the difference here is that step 3 6 7 11 12 13 14 16 is not mentioned in the other tutorial or other answers.

Comment: also, for someone who stuck with step 9, try to open  https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc in browser, then download it manually, then run `sudo apt-key add server-4.4.asc`.

Comment: `sudo apt-key add -` is deprecated: how to change that long command?

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this error because you didn't give access to mongodb
all you need to do is

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock

sudo service mongod restart
```

[you can use this medium.com link,too.](https://medium.com/@adhityad3v/mongodb-code-exited-status-14-f9f9f3d3e244)

now enjoy working with mongodb

Comment: Thanks, mate. I tried a lot with no success. But this helped

Answer (score 1):

Mongodb server-4.4.asc has a bug for ubuntu 20.04 on some machines.
I retry few times and I found a bug on "server-4.4.asc". I advice to install "server-4.2.asc" (ver 4.2 is OK and 4.4 has bug).

- see this link:
  [1]: https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-and-use-mongodb-on-ubuntu-2004/

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is already included in Ubuntu package repositories, but the official MongoDB repository provides the most up-to-date version and is the recommended way of installing the software. In this step, we will add this official repository to our server.

Ubuntu ensures the authenticity of software packages by verifying that they are signed with GPG keys, so we first have to import the key for the official MongoDB repository.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6
```

Next, we’ll add MongoDB repository details so apt will know where to download the packages. Issue the following command to create a list file for MongoDB.

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list
```

Finally, we’ll update the packages list.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

We’ll install the mongodb-org meta-package, which includes the daemon, configuration and init scripts, shell, and management tools on the server.

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
```

:)