# Proper index creation in mongodb timeseries collection

Tags: python, mongodb, indexing, pymongo, mongodb-compass

I am trying to create indexes for a nested mongo db timeseries collection.
My mongo db version, obtained by running `mongod --version`, is v3.6.8.

The timeseries schema follows the [suggested one](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/timeseries-collections/).

My collection has a schema like:

```
validator = {
    "$jsonSchema": {
        "bsonType": "object",
        "required": ["timestamp", "metadata", "measurements"],
        "properties": {
            "timestamp": {
                "bsonType": "long",
            },
            "metadata": {
                "bsonType": "object",
                "required": ["type", "sensor_id"],
                "properties": {
                    "type": {
                        "bsonType": "string",
                        "description": "Measurement type"
                    },
                    "sensor_id": {
                        "bsonType": "string",
                        "description": "sensor id"
                        }
                }
            },
            "measurement": {
                "bsonType": "array",
                "description": "must be an array and is required",
                "items": {
                    "bsonType": "double",
                    "description": "must be array of float and is required"
                },
                "minItems": 3,
                "maxItems": 3,
            },
        }
    }
}
```

When using Mongo db compass to access the db, going to the `Index` page shows in red the message: `Unrecognized expression '$toDouble()'`:
[image: Error on MongoDb Compass]

I thought this happens because I have not defined any Index yet. So in Pymongo, I try to create Indexes of the nested fields `type` and `sensor_id` with the line:

```
mydb.mycollection.create_index(
    [
        ("attrs.nested.sensor_id", pymongo.ASCENDING), 
        ("attrs.nested.type", pymongo.ASCENDING)
    ])
```

But the message error in Mongo Db compass keeps showing the error:

1. how to solve this Mongodb compass error

Furthermore, I am not sure the indexes are correctly defined, because if I create a fake index like:

```
mydb.mycollection.create_index(
    [
        ("attrs.nested.unexisting_field", pymongo.ASCENDING),
    ])
```

no error is generated although the specified field does not exist: 2) is there a way to check the index is correctly

Comment: The error of the pymongo index seems to be caused by an old version of mongodb, which I installed from ubuntu directly. I solved my issues by installing a new version following this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64796701/problems-installing-mongodb-on-ubuntu-20-04