# MongoDB Installation WSL 2

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/98.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 297 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-shell.
(Reading database ... 33550 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-shell_4.2.11_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-shell (4.2.11) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-server_4.2.11_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-server (4.2.11) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-mongos.
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-mongos_4.2.11_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-mongos (4.2.11) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-tools.
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-tools_4.2.11_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-tools (4.2.11) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org.
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org_4.2.11_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org (4.2.11) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-server (4.2.11) ...
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
dpkg: error processing package mongodb-org-server (--configure):
 installed mongodb-org-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up mongodb-org-shell (4.2.11) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-tools (4.2.11) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-mongos (4.2.11) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mongodb-org:
 mongodb-org depends on mongodb-org-server; however:
  Package mongodb-org-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mongodb-org (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
         Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-org-server
 mongodb-org
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Already reinstalled everything and keeps giving me the same error about the mongodb-org-server and mongodb-org, also the dpkg dependency problems and systemd as init system can't really understand much.

Just started learning about Linux because I want to learn Nginx server and such

Comment: Look like the version you have there is trying to utilise systemd which you don't have on WSL. You will be better served installing a version directly from the Mongodb website without systemd

Comment: Solution provided at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62496101/4567160) location helped me solve the issue.